# The abbreviation for wrapr::lambda doesn't work on windows

Tags: r, encoding

In the vignette of the wrapr function, it is written that the following code should work, although not respecting the standard naming usages for the name of a function.

```
library(wrapr)
wrapr::defineLambda()
sapply(1:4, λ(x, x^2))
```

It effectively works on my LINUX machine, but not on Windows where the interpreter seems to reject the special character. Is there some option to specify to get the example working?

Answer (score 0):

I think `defineLambda()` should be called within the `sapply` call

```
sapply(1:4, defineLambda()(x, x^2))
#[1]  1  4  9 16
```

or

```
sapply(1:4, 'λ'(x, x^2))
#[1]  1  4  9 16
```

Comment: No the full name of the λ is just 'lambda'. The function defineLambda is used to create the alias. But the problem is not to use the full name (obvioulsy it works) but to use the one-character abbreviation both on LINUX and Windows.

Comment: Hmm, when surrounding it with single quotes it works as well.

Comment: My understanding of the R naming rules is that R names/symbols need to start with a period or a letter. Like many other aspects of cross-platform behavior, I'm guessing that the allowable set of "letters" may vary from OS to OS as well as from local to locale.

Answer (score 0):

If a one-character abbreviation is what you care about, then it works with any of the alphabets on widnows. e.g.

```
a <- lambda(x, x^2)
sapply(1:4, a)
```

gives

```
[1]  1  4  9 16
```

I admit it's funny that the special character won't work on windows, though.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574385/can-i-escape-characters-in-variable-names) suggests using `backticks` to use special characters, like:

```
`\λ` <- lambda(x, x^2)
sapply(1:4, `\λ`)
```

which gives:

```
[1]  1  4  9 16
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue there around the locale, as suggested by 42. But there is possibily also an inconstency within R because  grepl("\\p{L}",intToUtf8(955),perl=TRUE) returns TRUE (the lambda is an alphabetic character)